# help with rsync (with samba) and ignoring perm/time/group/owner

Tags: rsync, file-transfer

so this is what I'm trying to use:

```
rsync -DHilrv --delete --progress /my-local-drive/ /my-network-share/
```

I've run the command above. After the operation was complete, I ran it again but this time I used ***--dry-run*** as an extra parameter, it wants to recopy/redo the transfer of the --same-- files affected on the first run.

The rsync log looks like this on the 1st and 2nd runs.

```
>f..Tp..... comics/comics1/Issue 0001.cbr
>f..Tp..... comics/comics1/Issue 0002.cbr
>f..Tp..... comics/comics1/Issue 0003.cbr
.
.
. --more files here--
.f.....g... apps/windows/internet/mobaxterm/slash/usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/pc
.f.....g... apps/windows/internet/mobaxterm/slash/usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/sanwa
```

Any ideas on what rsync parameters to use so that I get an empty list on the 2nd run?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although you are not using `-a` nor `-g` the second rsync `-i` is wanting to update the group owner of the file. Try adding as 2nd arg: `--no-g`.

Comment: -i is suppose to be for information only? Anyway, I tried your suggestion and I removed -i and I got the same results. Also from what I undertand, I only need to use -no-g if I am using a parameter like -a?